# Model not reflected in QTreeView

Tags: qt

I am a QT and C++ newbie and I am trying to bind QTreeView to a QStandardItemModel. The code below compiles, but the widget doesn't get populated with the childItem. Anyone know why?

```
#include <QStandardItemModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTreeView *qtree = ui->treeView;

    QStandardItemModel model;
    QStandardItem *item = model.invisibleRootItem();
    QStandardItem *childItem = new QStandardItem(QString("child item"));
    item->appendRow(childItem);
    qtree->setModel( &model );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the instance of the model, and then promptly destroy it when the `MainWindow` constructor returns. Your model is a local variable!

You want the model to be a value member in the widget. I also suggest to disregard the silly Qt Creator template code and **not** hold the `ui` member by pointer, but directly by value. The extra pointer indirection is pointless and a premature pessimization. It made sense 15 years ago when compilers and disks were 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than they are now.

```
// mainwindow.h
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Ui::MainWindow ui; // by value!
  QStandardItemModel model; // by value!
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget * parent == nullptr);
  // Let the compiler do the hard work: the default destructor is just fine!
}
```

```
// mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) :
  QMainWindow{parent}
{
  ui.setupUi(this);
  auto root = model.invisibleRootItem();
  root->appendRow(new QStandardItem{QStringLiteral("child item")});
  ui.treeView->setModel(&model);
}
```